# Executing a script in .zshrc

Tags: shell, zsh

I'm trying to use [z (link)](https://github.com/rupa/z) to make navigating a little easier. The problem is that I have the following in my .zshrc file, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/x/z
alias z='/home/x/z/z.sh'
. z
```

For some reason, the last command never seems to work. If I do it by hand after opening the shell, it's fine but executing it within the .zshrc will not work.

Comment: Shouldn't the last line be `. x` rather than `. z`?

Comment: Whoops, typo. Fixed.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `source` (and its alias `.`) doesn't consult the list of aliases. Does it work any better if you just specify the full path to the file on that third line? (Note that you can use `~` as a shorthand for the path to your home directory.)

Comment: Adding to @MichaelKjörling 's answer, you can prepend a backslash to commands to prevent aliasing (e.g. `\source z`).

Answer (score 2):

You are misusing aliases. You should use a variable instead.

```
z='/home/x/z/z.sh' . "$z"
```

Aliases are for commands. For example,

```
alias l=ls
```

That being said, this should work:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/x/z alias z='/home/x/z/z.sh' alias .='. ' . z
```

The `.='. '` alias enables alias expansion. If the first word after `.` is an
alias, it will be expanded.

Also note that `/home/x/z` does not need to be in your path to source `z.sh`.